# If it is possible to search mailFolder using msgraph API by mailFolder displayName

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I want to implement some functionallity to allow user to search mailFolder using msGraph API

If it is possible to search mailFolder using msgraph API by mailFolder **displayName**
In documentation I didnt find any mentions about how to search mailFolder. It only shows how to get mailFolder by ID. Can we even search mailFolder? Or search is not supported for mailFolders?
Thanks for any answers or suggetions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` query parameter and search for a folder the match `displayName`

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$filter=displayName eq 'name'
```

or if `displayName` starts with some value

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$filter=startswith(displayName,'name')
```

Resource:

[Filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it only filtering root mailFolders. I need to do search in the whole maibox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible - in a 2 step process.

First, get all mailfolders (Root- and subfolders) of a mailbox:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<[ID] or UPN of mailbox>/mailFolders/delta
```

This gives you an array with all mailFolders. In my case I store them in $MailFolders (Powershell)

Secondly, get only the one which has the desired displayName out of the array.

For example, in Powershell, I do this:

```
$Mailfolder = $MailFolders | where displayName -eq "<displayName of desired folder>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all root folders than loop through them and search for their childfolders.
My example only searches the inbox for the childfolder but you should get the idea:

```
          var folders = await graphClient.Users[user.id].MailFolders.Request().Filter("displayname eq '"+DestFolderName+"'").GetAsync();
                if (folders is null || folders.Count != 1)
                {
                    folders = await graphClient.Users[user.id].MailFolders.Request().Filter("displayname eq 'Posteingang'").GetAsync();
                    if (folders.Count == 1)
                    {
                        var childfolders = await graphClient.Users[user.id].MailFolders[folders.First().Id].ChildFolders.Request().Filter("displayname eq '"+DestFolderName+"'").GetAsync();
                        if (childfolders is null || folders.Count != 1)
                            return BadRequest("Could not find folder!");
                        else
                            folderid= childfolders.First().Id;
                    }
                    else
                        return BadRequest("Could not find folder!");
                }
                else
                    folderid= folders.First().Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapted Tekkion's solution to work recursive and with new SDK API (for example Mailfolders.Request() isn't working here any more)

c#

```
public GraphServiceClient GraphClient { get; set; }
        
        public async Task<Microsoft.Graph.Models.MailFolder> searchMailFolder(Microsoft.Graph.Models.MailFolder parentFolder, string displayName)
        {
             var subfolders = await GraphClient.Me.MailFolders[parentFolder.Id].ChildFolders.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter += "displayname eq '" + displayName + "'";
            }
            );
            if (subfolders.Value.Count == 1)
            {
                return subfolders.Value.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            else if (subfolders.Value.Count == 0)
            {
                subfolders = await GraphClient.Me.MailFolders[parentFolder.Id].ChildFolders.GetAsync();
                           foreach(MailFolder folder in subfolders.Value) 
                {
                    var subfolders1 = await searchMailFolder(folder, displayName, user, guiForm);
                    if(subfolders1!= null)
                        return subfolders1;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public async Task<string> searchMailFolder(string displayName)
        {
            var folder = await searchMailFolder(await GraphClient.Me.MailFolders["msgfolderroot"].GetAsync(),displayName);

            return folder.Id;
        }
```

First method searches for a subfolder with the specific displayName. If it isn't found, search all subfolders of this subfolder recursive with the same function. If it is found, return the folder.

Second method starts first method with the rootfolder (msgfolderroot) and returns the id.